# Updating static variables in a Timer Task

Tags: java, timer

I have a simple Java timer set up, and I have a static boolean before it. Is there a way to update that boolean inside the timer?

I want to update the boolean named `b` that I declare in the first line inside of `timerTask`. `b` is static and cannot be changed inside of a timer task normally. Is there a way to get around this?

```java
boolean b = false;
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //update the value of b
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
timerTask.run();
```

Comment: By the way, the `Timer` and `TimerTask` classes have been supplanted by the Executors framework added to Java 5, as noted on their Javadoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a reference to update the value. An easy thread-save solution is the usage of `AtomicBoolean` as follows

```
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        AtomicBoolean b = new AtomicBoolean();
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(b);
                b.set(true);
                System.out.println(b);
            }
        };
        timerTask.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me solve my issue. Btw, may I ask, what's the difference between an AtomicBoolean and a boolean?

Comment: Your two calls to println are not thread-safe. Between those lines another thread can be changing the content of the `AtomicBoolean`.